# jmeter prev.getResponseDataAsString getting wrong return

Tags: jmeter

I have a looping process that will extract some values from a web service (working) and loop through to pull all the information for each value (working).

I need to capture the whole return into a variable so I can modify it and post it back up later.

Screenshot:

[image]

When the "Baseline for ..." get kicks in, I get the proper response

But the "Get response" BeanShell PreProcessor is picking up old responses

Screenshot:

[image]

Given where my "Get response" object is, I would assume the:
vars.put("ResponceData", prev.getResponseDataAsString());

...would grab the response from "Baseline for ${ID} of site ${callSite}".  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong test element. Beanshell PreProcessor is being executed **before** request therefore it acts properly and returns response from the **previous** request instead of current one. You need to change it to the [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) and your code will start working as you expect.

---

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible, if you need to save response data into a JMeter Variable you can do it using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). According [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article the relevant configuration will be something like:

- Reference Name: `ResponceData`
- Regular Expression: (?s)(^.*)
- Template: `$1$`

  [image: JMeter Regular Expression]

If you face a JMeter limitation which cannot be worked around without using scripting make sure you are using the most performing scripting language, since JMeter 3.1 it is [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)